# Derivation $X^2$-pdf (Chi square) for $k$ degrees of freedom

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Could someone explain the steps of the derivation of the $X^2$-pdf for k degrees of freedom in the following article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution

or give an alternative simpler proof ?

We consider the RV's $X_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$ togheter as a point $(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ in $\mathbb R^n$. To calculate the probability $X^2(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 = x$ we simply integrate over the subset of $\mathbb R^n$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 = x$ - that is the points with norm squared from the origin equal to $x$. This is equivalent to integrate over the subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with points having norm equal to $\sqrt x$.

However from here I'm lost, and I don't know why the argument regarding some shell-volume is true.

I have tried consulting the book written by Hatashi, but the proof goes on in the same way, where we consider some hypershell.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your $X$ is an $N(0,1)$ random variable.

[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed the random variables are $\sim N(0,1)$. Thanks, for your proof. May I ask what is the source ?

Comment: It's from the notes of a statistics course I took. Also even if your RV is not normal, for sufficiently large $n$ we can assume it to be normal according to central limit theorem.

Comment: Are those notes available somewhere ? It's an interesting proof.

Comment: Also, could you provide the proof that the sum of independent Gamma variables has the distribution as stated in your proof ?

Comment: Notes are available in our university webmail. But you cannot access it without an account.

Comment: Sum of $n$ $Gamma(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ RVs is a $Gamma(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ can be proved using the change of variable formula for joint distributions.

Comment: Hi Again, Mathew. Can you tell me how you rewrite the integral in the proof ? Is it integration by substitution where $\int^a_b f(g(x))g'(x) dx = \int^{g(a)}_{g(b)} f(x) dx$ using the substitution $s = u^2$ ? If yes, how can we apply this rule ? - I cannot get the integral into the proper form $\int^a_b f(g(x))g'(x) dx $? If no, what method are you using to change the integral ?

Comment: When you change the variable it is better to use a different notation for the variable to avoid confusion (Use $t$ instead of $x$ in the RHS of the first equation you have written. $t=g(x)$). If $s=u^2$ $du=s^{-\frac{1}{2}}ds$. Subtitute this in the integral and change the limits.

Comment: But $s=u^2 \Rightarrow 1 = du^2/ds = 2u \cdot du/ds \Rightarrow 1/2u = du/ds$. We know $s=u^2 \Rightarrow s^{1/2} = |u|$. So why may we replace $u$ by $s^{1/2}$ when $s^{1/2} = |u|$. Is it because our limits assures $u$ is positive, thus $|u| = u$ in the interval of integration ?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry I missed a $\frac{1}{2}$ there.

Comment: What about the $|u|$ ?

Comment: Yes because the limit interval is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1 \sim {\rm Gamma}(\alpha_1, \beta)$ and $X_2 \sim {\rm Gamma}(\alpha_2, \beta)$ be independent Gamma random variables with the same scale parameter $\beta$ (here we use the parametrization such that ${\rm E}[X_1] = \alpha_1 \beta$).  Then the density of $Y = X_1 + X_2$ is given by $$\begin{align*} f_Y(y) &= \int_{t=0}^y f_{X_1}(t) f_{X_2}(y-t) \, dt \\ &= \int_{t=0}^y \frac{t^{\alpha_1 - 1} e^{-t/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha_1) \beta^{\alpha_1}} \cdot \frac{(y-t)^{\alpha_2 - 1} e^{-(y-t)/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha_2) \beta^{\alpha_2}} \, dt \\ &= \frac{e^{-y/\beta}}{\beta^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)} \int_{t=0}^y t^{\alpha_1-1} (y-t)^{\alpha_2-1} \, dt \\ &= \frac{e^{-y/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2) \beta^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)} \int_{u=0}^1 (yu)^{\alpha_1-1} (y(1-u))^{\alpha_2-1} y \, du \\ &= \frac{y^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2-1} e^{-y/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2) \beta^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)} \int_{u=0}^1 u^{\alpha_1-1} (1-u)^{\alpha_2-1} \, du \\ &= \frac{y^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2-1} e^{-y/\beta}}{\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2) \beta^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}}, 
\end{align*}$$  where we see that the last integral is simply that for a beta density over its support.  Thus $Y \sim {\rm Gamma}(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2, \beta)$, as claimed.

Comment: Also, if you know that if $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are IID exponential variables with common scale parameter $\beta$, then $S = \sum X_i$ is Gamma with shape parameter $\alpha = n$.  So by extension, the sum of Gamma variables is also Gamma (being themselves the sum of exponential variables), with shape parameter equal to the sum of their individual shapes.  But this only applies when the shapes are all positive integers, whereas the above applies for any positive shapes.

Comment: How do you get the fourth equality ?

Comment: Does the beta density over its support result in $\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)/\Gamma(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$ ?

Comment: You will need to be a little more specific:  if are you asking about how $$\int_{t=0}^y t^{\alpha_1-1}(y-t)^{\alpha_2-1} \, dt = \int_{u=0}^1 (yu)^{\alpha_1-1}(y(1-u))^{\alpha_2-1} y \, du$$ then this is because of the choice of substitution $t = yu$, $dt = y \, du$, which is a scaling transformation.

Comment: The density of a beta distribution with parameters $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ **includes** the $\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)/(\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2))$ term.  The integral of any probability density over its support is equal to $1$.  I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: Is the proof valid only for $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb Z$ ? Or does it apply to any number $\in \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Since $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are shape parameters of a gamma distribution, they must both be positive reals.  The proof I furnished is also valid for $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 > 0$, since the beta distribution also requires this condition for the integral to converge.  They need not be integers; if that were the case, then the beta density could be written in terms of factorials rather than gamma functions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function
Does this prove that the Beta-integral is equal to $\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)/\Gamma(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$ for any $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes.  After cancellation with the normalizing constant in the beta density, it evaluates to 1.  However, again note that because any density function must be nonnegative over its support, we must have $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 > 0$.  The singularity of the gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ at $z = 0$ prevents defining the beta and gamma distributions for negative shape parameter values.

Comment: After cancellation with the normalizing constant in the beta density, it evaluates to 1 you mean: the integral is equal to Γ(α1)Γ(α2)/Γ(α1+α2) so the fractions cancel ?

Comment: Yes.  The final integral from $0$ to $1$ is a beta integral, which equals $\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)/\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$.  The beta **density** is the integrand of the beta integral, times the normalizing constant $\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)/(\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2))$, which is necessary in order for the density to integrate to $1$.